# ArgumentParser object has no attribute 'add_option' on passing flags

Tags: python, argparse

Day three of learning python.

I'm attempting to understand how to pass flags from the command line and call a function with that flag. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    parser.add_option("-l", action="callback", callback=printLogs)
AttributeError: 'ArgumentParser' object has no attribute 'add_option'
```

The code is here:

```
import argparse

def printLogs():
    print("logs!")

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-e','--entry', type=str, help='New entry',required=False)
parser.add_option("-l", action="callback", callback=printLogs)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

I can understand that parser.add_option doesn't exist for parser. This much is clear. I can also see that the OptionParser has been deprecated as per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960880/understanding-optionparser). So, OptionParser is out.

The question being: How do I parse the -l argument such that the printLogs function is called when its passed?

Comment: What's your question? Do you want to know how to translate the callback option into the `argparse` API?

Comment: Sorry, just re-read that. No question! I blame my fever. Will update.

Comment: There's no `add_option` method. Use `add_argument` instead. Also there's no `callback` action, see the documentation about [`action`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html#action) to see which available actions are there and to learn how to create new actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would implement this is:

```
import argparse

def printLogs():
    print("logs!")

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-e','--entry', type=str, help='New entry')
parser.add_argument("-l", action="store_true", help='print logs')

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.l:
    printLogs()
```

The primary purpose of `argparse` is to parse the input (`sys.argv`), and give you a set of argument values (`args` is a simple `namespace` object).  `callbacks` is a `optparse` concept that have not been included in `argparse`.

The `FooAction` example in the docs, http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html#action, does something like this `optparse` callback.  It prints some information when called, and then does the important thing - set a value in the namespace.

Comment: Perfect, that explains exactly what I needed. Thanks.